# Syntax Error whilst trying to sort descending with limit

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code:

```
//Get latest version of regulation related to this CE Group
$rstmp = CustomQuery("
SELECT * 
  FROM EURegulations 
 ORDER 
    BY ValidFrom DESC 
 LIMIT 1 
 where CEGroupFk='".$values['CEGroupFk']."'
");
$datatmp = db_fetch_array($rstmp);
```

The purpose is to return the latest item in that list that is relevant to that foreign key.

I am getting the following message:

> 1. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>      near 'where CEGroupFk='5'' at line 1;
> 2. 256;

The array seems to  returning good data:

> 1. Array ( [EURegulationReference] => test [EURegulationTitle] => test [ValidFrom] => 2019-06-19 00:00:00 [ValidTo] => 2019-06-28 00:00:00
>      [Attachment] => [CEGroupFk] => 5 [E...;
> 2. Array ( [EURegulationPk] => 2 ) ;

I am assuming that there is a problem with my customquery code but cannot see it?

Comment: The clauses in a SELECT have a specific order. [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: ok so what should it be? please

Comment: "I am assuming that there is a problem with my customquery code but cannot see it".  Have you checked MySQL documentation the SQL syntax?  Next time check documentation first before posting your question here.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order by clause  must be placed  after the where clause

```
$rstmp = CustomQuery("
  SELECT * FROM EURegulations 
   where CEGroupFk='".$values['CEGroupFk']."'
   ORDER BY ValidFrom DESC LIMIT 1
   ");
```